# Reading material similar to ‘geometry of linear groups’ chapter of Suzuki ‘Group theory I’

Tags: gr.group-theory, reading-list

I am trying to find sources and other texts that cover similar material as in the title in Suzuki’s ‘group theory I’. This involves, definition and properties of buildings, complexes, the Weyl group and such. One book I was suggested was simple groups of Lie type by R.W Carter. I have found a copy of this in a library but it’s about an hour away and want to see if it’s worth the journey.
Thanks

Comment: It is worth the journey.

Comment: I shall be getting it then. Thanks

Comment: For buildings I recommend Ronan's book.

Comment: I agree with Geoff. Carter's book on simple groups of Lie type is well worth the journey.

Comment: Yes, Carter's book is an all-time great! I've got a .djvu electronic version and am happy to send it to you if you drop me an email.

Comment: I highly recommend Abramenko--Brown's book. This is a redo/expansion of Brown's book, which is free on his website and has all the same background stuff: https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~kbrown/buildings/brown1988.pdf